# How to add picture at nav menu?

Tags: html, css

I want to do menu like bellowing code. And i want to add picture in menu but different picture. When I add picture, than i pas through to Menu 1 to MENU 2 picture not change to other. First picture stay table in all time. How can I solve this.

A mean, When I add pictures to menu 1 (first picture), I see the first picture in menu 2. But I want to just see picture 1 in MENU1

```
<div class="tabbable"> 
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">MENU1    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">MENU2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane  " id="tab1">
      <p>MENU1 ITEMS 
      </p>
     <--! I want to add picture1 HERE---!>
      <div class="img"><img src="picture1.jpg" alt="" style="width:100px;height:100px;></div>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane " id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
     <--! I want to add picture2 HERE---!>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: show us css also

Comment: I have no css. I am using bootstrap command. But I am new. Css is necessery ?

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: I don't get the problem. What about adding an <img > tag? Can you please check your question. What do you mean by  "than i pas through to Menu 1 to MENU 2 " ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: @smartmeta I added but when I pass through to menu 1 to menu 2, fisrt picture couldnt change. Stay in screen all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add bootstrap script as:**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Also** add `active` class to `tab-pane` that active

**See code:**

```css
    img{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="tabbable"> 
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">MENU1    </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">MENU2</a></li>
      </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <p>MENU1 ITEMS 
          </p>
           <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mG2d.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
           <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXoO.png"/>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find copy/paste example from [official bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#tabs)

All you need to do is to add your images in the appropriate div's below.

And modify html/css if needed to match your exact needs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do it using the img tag or in css

HTML:

```
<img src="Your_img_adress" alt="">
```

or using html and css:
Html:

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

Css:

```
.img {
   background-url: (your-url);
   height: 100px; /* You can change this if you want */
   width: auto; /* You can change this if you want */
}
```

Comment: Thank you but, again same error. I added belowing MENU1 and when i pass to MENU2. Picture still on the screen. But i dont show in MENU2, I want to just see ,MENU1

Comment: press ctrl + shift + I that will take you to the inspection tab

Comment: Then see. Personally I think that the height is too much to be shown in the nav bar

Comment: or you  might have made the position as absolute

Comment: Please post the `.css` file

Answer (score -1):

A better way would be to use the `<img>`tag and use it as

```
<img src"image link" alt=''>
```

If you want more flexibility you can also use the bootstrap images classes or add/change properties to the `image` class in the `.css` file.